# Redshift - generate_series workaround?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, generate-series

I have a table for machine installations in this way:

```
installationID, machineID, installed_at, uninstalled_at
A, 1, 2020-01-01, Null
B, 2, 2020-01-01, 2020-01-02
C, 3, 2020-01-02, Null
D, 2, 2020-01-04, Null
```

I need a query that returns the number of installed machines per day. Like this:

```
Date, installed
2020-01-01, 2
2020-01-02, 3
2020-01-03, 2 
2020-01-04, 3
```

I know that given a date, say '2020-01-03', I can get the number of installed machines as follows:

```
SELECT date, count(machineID) 
from installs 
where installed_at >= '2020-01-03' 
and (uninstalled_at is Null or uninstalled_at <= '2020-01-03')
```

Also, I know how to solve this problem in PostgreSQL:

```sql
select generate_series dt, count(*) n
from  generate_series('2020-01-01'::timestamp , '2020-01-15'::timestamp, '1 day')  
left join tbl on installed_at <= generate_series and ( uninstalled_at is null or uninstalled_at > generate_series)
group by generate_series
order by generate_series;
```

(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67950775/1494511)

However, when I try this in Redshift, I first need to change the `generate_series` to the following:

```sql
WITH TS as (
  SELECT '2021-06-01'::date - (n || ' days')::interval generate_series from generate_series (1, 5) n
) 
select generate_series dt, count(*) n
from  TS
left join tbl on installed_at <= generate_series and ( uninstalled_at is null or uninstalled_at > generate_series)
group by generate_series
order by generate_series;
```

Note `generate_series('2020-01-01'::timestamp , '2020-01-15'::timestamp, '1 day')` becoming `SELECT '2021-06-01'::date - (n || ' days')::interval generate_series from generate_series (1, 5) n`, since the syntax in Redshift being a little different. But that is not the problem.

After running the above query I get `Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables`
Which is an error due to the nature of Redshift Massive multiprocessing (MPP), as described below:

> The generate_series() command is not fully supported on Amazon Redshift.
> It can be used for queries that run solely on the Leader node, but cannot be used in queries that involve tables because they involve cluster nodes. The only workaround is to create a large table with lots of values and join to it to get a range of numbers. (A bit of work up front, but then it works fine.)

(From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42106596/1494511)

But this comment does not give me any clear directions on how to perform such a query in redshift.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good work-around . . . except by using an existing table.  Assuming your table has enough rows:

```
with dates as (
      select '2020-01-01'::date + (row_number() over () - 1) interval '1 day' as date
      from tbl
      limit 4
     )
select d.date, count(*) as cnt
from  dates d left join
      tbl
      on installed_at <= d.date and
         (uninstalled_at is null or uninstalled_at > d.date)
group by d.date
order by d.date;
```